# Is there a way to trigger an animation once something collides with it then queue free in Godot?

Tags: godot

I have an animation that makes a powerup Sprite scale down and disappear. I want it to activate when the Player Scene touches the powerup then queue free, but I cant find a way to mention this animation in the player script(tell the engine to start the animation). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Having the player character reach into the powerup and start the animation should be possible. However, I'll not recommend it, as it goes against encapsulation and the single responsibility principles. Or to put it on more pragmatic terms: if you need to modify the powerup scene, you might also have to modify the player character scene so that it keeps working.

Of course the powerup and the player character need to interact somehow. What I'm going on about is that their interaction should not rely on any internal detail of their scenes. If you look at the advice from software engineering they will tell you they must exchange "a message" which is modern language often means a method call form one to the other, however in Godot it can mean a signal.

Speaking of signals, we should treat physics as external to your code. We configure your physics bodies or areas, and the physics engine will send signals about the collision to which our code reacts. We should start there: where are you getting the signal, on powerup or the player character?

If you are getting the signal on the powerup, you would do this:

- Call a method on the player character to let it know it got a powerup.

  - Then that method on the player character script will setup whatever the effect of the power up is.
- Start the animation.
- Queue free.

If you are getting the signal on the player character, you would do this:

- Call a method on the powerup to let it know it has been collected.

  - Then that method on the powerup script will start the animation and queue free.
- Setup whatever the effect of the power up is (the player character might need  to figure out which powerup it is, which could be done by calling methods which return information about the powerup or read its properties).

*By the way, you can use `has_method` to check for the method before calling. In fact, I would encourage deciding on a method name that you can use for everything that the player character interacts with. You can pass a parameter where you specify details. This would act as an interface. So we have what software engineers would call loosely coupled code.*

*We can have can have decoupled code using a signal/even bus or with resource based communication, yet I have no reason to believe you need that in this particular case.*

---

Similarly the animation is something external to your code. You want the animation to let you know when it finished. There are a couple ways to do that:

- Using the `"animation_finished"` signal of the `AnimationPlayer`. You can either from the editor or from code… Or you can `yield` on it.
- Or you can add a method call track on the animation and have it call a method on the powerup script (which might be `queue_free` directly).

---

If you really want to reach into the other scene, you can do so by calling `get_node` on it. For example, the player character script can call `get_node` on the powerup to get a node inside of the powerup scene, such as the `AnimationPlayer`.

*And, again I remind you that if in the future - for whatever reason - you decide to move or rename the animation or the `AnimationPlayer`, this code would break. So you would have to remember to update it too. Besides, if this is the approach you will take for everything the player character interacts with, its code can become a mess over time.*